# spring-cloud-aws error No database type found for engine:'aurora'

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

I have a spring boot application that I am trying to connect to RDS instance (MySQL). Here is my App

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRdsInstance(databaseName="*****", dbInstanceIdentifier="****", username="****",password="******")
@EnableContextCredentials(accessKey="*****", secretKey="****")
@EnableContextRegion(region="****")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

when I try `mvn spring-boot:run`,

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dubba': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No database type found for engine:'aurora'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at sample.traditional.config.Application.main(Application.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Same problem here, ever got it to work?

Comment: no luck here. if you find out, please let us know. thanks

Comment: Got it solved, hopefully it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Aurora wasn't officially in the framework ([Spring Cloud for Amazon Web Services](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws)), even though it is basically MySQL.

It is part of 1.1.0 release, as of today (11.5.2016) in [stable version](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/releases/tag/v1.1.0.RELEASE).

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

When the release version becomes available on Maven, simply replace the RC2 with RELEASE.

Comment: so adding these dependency is sufficient?

Comment: I had this dependency in version 1.0.4 and got the same error as you. I reckon you must have some dependency that includes the older version of jdbc aws driver (such as 1.0.4). It is a good practice to include only the dependencies you really need and the whole aws sdk.